# MYSQL procedimiento con error sin justificar

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
BEGIN
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS indicesaimportar;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS basededatosactual;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE indicesaimportar SELECT TABLE_NAME, INDEX_NAME, SEQ_IN_INDEX, COLUMN_NAME, (CASE WHEN NON_UNIQUE = 0 THEN 'UNIQUE' WHEN INDEX_TYPE = 'FULLTEXT' THEN 'FULLTEXT' ELSE '' END) AS 'INDEX_TYPE' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA =DATABASE();
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE basededatosactual SELECT TABLE_NAME, INDEX_NAME, SEQ_IN_INDEX, COLUMN_NAME, (CASE WHEN NON_UNIQUE = 0 THEN 'UNIQUE' WHEN INDEX_TYPE = 'FULLTEXT' THEN 'FULLTEXT' ELSE '' END) AS 'INDEX_TYPE' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA =DATABASE();
ALTER TABLE basededatosactual ADD id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE indicesaimportar ADD id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
INSERT INTO indicesaimportar (TABLE_NAME, INDEX_NAME, SEQ_IN_INDEX, COLUMN_NAME, INDEX_TYPE) VALUES ('productos', 'caca', 1, 'id', 'UNIQUE');
INSERT INTO indicesaimportar (TABLE_NAME, INDEX_NAME, SEQ_IN_INDEX, COLUMN_NAME, INDEX_TYPE) VALUES ('productos', 'caca', 2, 'nombre', 'UNIQUE');
CALL Importarindices();
END
```

Que llama a la siguiente funcion:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Importarindices`()
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE IndexIsThere INTEGER;
DECLARE _TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(512);
DECLARE _INDEX_NAME VARCHAR(64);
DECLARE _SEQ_IN_INDEX BIGINT(2);
DECLARE _COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(64);
DECLARE _INDEX_TYPE VARCHAR(15);
DECLARE ANEXOTYPE VARCHAR(50);
/*--variable que le pone fin a todo*/
DECLARE fin INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
/*--el SELECT que voy a usar*/
DECLARE compararindices CURSOR FOR
SELECT a.TABLE_NAME, a.INDEX_NAME, a.SEQ_IN_INDEX, a.COLUMN_NAME, a.INDEX_TYPE FROM indicesaimportar a LEFT JOIN basededatosactual b ON (a.TABLE_NAME = b.TABLE_NAME AND a.INDEX_NAME = b.INDEX_NAME AND a.SEQ_IN_INDEX = b.SEQ_IN_INDEX AND a.COLUMN_NAME = b.COLUMN_NAME AND a.INDEX_TYPE = b.INDEX_TYPE) WHERE b.id IS null;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET fin=1;
OPEN compararindices;
iniciodeimportacion: LOOP
FETCH compararindices INTO _TABLE_NAME, _INDEX_NAME, _SEQ_IN_INDEX, _COLUMN_NAME, _INDEX_TYPE;
IF fin = 1 THEN
LEAVE iniciodeimportacion;
END IF;
SELECT (CASE WHEN _INDEX_TYPE='INDEX' OR _INDEX_TYPE='' THEN 'INDEX' WHEN _INDEX_TYPE='UNIQUE' THEN 'UNIQUE INDEX' WHEN _INDEX_TYPE='FULLTEXT' THEN 'FULLTEXT INDEX' END) INTO ANEXOTYPE;
IF _SEQ_IN_INDEX= 0 THEN
SET @sqlstmt = CONCAT('CREATE OR REPLACE ', ANEXOTYPE,' ',_INDEX_NAME,' ON ',
DATABASE(),'.',_TABLE_NAME,' (',_COLUMN_NAME,');');
PREPARE st FROM @sqlstmt;
EXECUTE st;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;
ELSE
SET @sqlstmt = CONCAT(IF((select count(index_name) from basededatosactual where table_name = _TABLE_NAME and index_name = _INDEX_NAME)>0,'', CONCAT('DROP INDEX ',_INDEX_NAME,' ON ',database(),'.', _TABLE_NAME,';')),' ALTER TABLE ',database(),'.', _TABLE_NAME,' ADD ', ANEXOTYPE,' ', _INDEX_NAME,' (',(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME SEPARATOR ', ') FROM indicesaimportar WHERE INDEX_TYPE = _INDEX_TYPE AND _TABLE_NAME = TABLE_NAME),');');
select @sqlstmt AS '** DEBUG:';
PREPARE st FROM @sqlstmt;
EXECUTE st;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;
END IF;
END LOOP iniciodeimportacion;
CLOSE compararindices;
/*
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE indicesaimportar;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE basededatosactual;
/*END IF;*/
END
```

y dice que algo esta equivocado cerca de "add table.... unique index " y no esta nada equivocado, he utilizado un debugger y el codigo @sqlstmt en ese momento es el siguiente!

```
DROP INDEX caca ON nuevo.productos; ALTER TABLE nuevo.productos ADD UNIQUE INDEX caca (id, nombre);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y como se puede apreciar la sintaxis del codigo es correcto, cual es el problema? alguien lo sabe?

Comment: y dice que algo esta equivocado - Pero que dice que esta equivocado ?? Si tienes un error ayudaría mucho ver ESE error.

Comment: añadi el errorr, exactamente com lo describi, esta es la captura

Comment: Al crear esa tabla, generas un error de sintaxis.. Eso es lo que dice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se genera porque las consultas preparadas no permiten ejecutar múltiples sentencias (multi-statements) dentro de la misma cadena separadas por `;`.

> [13.5 Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html)
>
> ...
>
> SQL syntax for prepared statements does not support multi-statements (that is, multiple statements within a single string separated by ; characters).
>
> ...

Ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c47475af98b4467ca111a83bfff6873c).